# Java: parsing a string

Tags: java, parsing

I have a series of strings, each of the format :

`"{3.242, 87611}, {5.658, 7.3731}, {5.547, 8.7631} ......"`

Each pair of numbers in curly brackets represents one Latitude/Longitude point (and each number is of **type double**).

I want to *parse* the string **so that each point in the string is represented as a separate Lat/Lon object, that I store in a list of points.**

I am pretty new to Java (and parsing). I have been looking at a lot of examples but I'm still really confused as to how to even begin.
How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Step 1) Try something.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regExp` to fetch points first,

```
String str = "{3.242, 87611},{5.658, 7.3731}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{(.*?)\\}");
Matcher match = pattern.matcher(str);

while(match.find()) {
   System.out.println(match.group(1));
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
3.242, 87611
5.658, 7.3731
```

Now you can just use [`split`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java) to find two points and you can parse them to `Double`. Note here `(.*?)`  is a group which means any `String`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already have this String in some variable `str`, you can split `str` into it's component numbers

```
String[] splitNumbers = str.split("[{}, ]+");
```

then iterate over this list and use each pair of numbers to construct a Coordinate object.

```
Coordinate[] coords = new Coordinate[splitNumbers.length/2];
for(int i=0; i < splitNumbers.length-2;i+=2){
    double longitude = Double.paresDouble(splitNumbers[i]);
    double latitude = Double.paresDoublesplitNUmbers[i+1]);
    coords[i/2] = new Coordinate(longitude,latitude);
 }
```